# Need help to convert pandas dataframe(iloc) to numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to write a code for linear regression with multiple variables. I am retrieving data from txt file to 'data' variable. I am trying to initialize the first two columns to variable x which is working fine. In the next the step while trying to add a np.ones array to this 2d array I am getting unrecognizable data. I have added the code and value of array x before adding 'np.ones' array and after. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.
My code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('ex1data2.txt',header = None)
x = data.iloc[:,0:2]
y = data.iloc[:,2]
m=len(x)

y = y[:,np.newaxis]
x = (x - np.mean(x))/np.std(x)
ones = np.ones((m,1))

x = np.hstack((ones,x))
```

Value of x before step np.hstack()

```
           0         1
0   0.131415 -0.226093
1  -0.509641 -0.226093
2   0.507909 -0.226093
3  -0.743677 -1.554392
4   1.271071  1.102205
5  -0.019945  1.102205
```

Value after step np.hstack()

```
[[ 1.00000000e+00  1.31415422e-01 -2.26093368e-01]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -5.09640698e-01 -2.26093368e-01]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  5.07908699e-01 -2.26093368e-01]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -7.43677059e-01 -1.55439190e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00  1.27107075e+00  1.10220517e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00 -1.99450507e-02  1.10220517e+00]]
```

Comment: The int array of `ones` is coerced to float. What is your question exactly?

Comment: It seems to me that you might got confused by the "scientific notation" of numpy,  0.131415 becames 1.31415422e-01  where e-01 means 10**-1

Comment: I don't understand how the value of ones became float and the other rows become so big after the decimal. Because of that, I am a getting error in calculating gradient descent.

Comment: You mean, you don't know what [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) is? This is pretty basic stuff, stop doing gradient descent and read that link. Note that the values are exactly the same, they are just represented in a different format when printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is doing exactly what you want. It is just notation 1.31415422e-01 = 1.31415422 * 10^(-1) = 0.131415

Based on the title of the question. If you want to keep working with a pandas DataFrame instead of receiving a numpy array, I recommend that instead of

`x = np.hstack((ones,x))`

you use

`x = x.assign(ones = 1)`

That will keep x as a DataFrame with a new column of only 1's called "ones".